# Angular - Trigger Grandparent Function When Grandchild Function executes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I have the following component structure:

Component A -> Component B -> Component C

In the Component C template, I have a button, that when clicked calls a function in the 'code behind'.

What I am trying to achieve is every time that function is called, I want a function in Component A to be called.

Component A is the Granparent of Component C

I could pass an EventEmitter down to Component B then onto Component C but I don't want to do that.

I've tried the following:

**SharedService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor() {}

  valueClicked() {
    console.log('Value Clicked has been called');
    this.subject.next({});
  }

  getValue(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**ComponentC.ts Method**

```
public buttonClicked(): void {
    this.sharedService.valueClicked();
  }
```

**ComponentA.ts ngOnInit**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.sharedService.getValue().subscribe(message => {
      console.log('Function Called');
    });
  }
```

I would have expected that everytime the function is called in Component C that Component A would log 'Function Called' but this is not the case.

Comment: Since it is a hierarchical relationship you can inject grand-parent component A into grand-child component C's constructor and then call the method directly. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: What is the current behaviour?

Comment: I don't want to inject the GrandParent component. I am specifically looking to achieve this through a shared service and raising some event on the GrandChild that the GrandParent is subscribed to

Answer (score 0):

You can use take(1) operator that takes just one value and immediately completes the chain (no need to use asObservable).

```
getValue(): Observable<any> {
   return this.subject.take(1);
}
```

Now every time you do this.subject.take(1) you'll receive one value immediately and complete.

Comment: That doesn't work - Property 'take' does not exist on type BehaviourSubject<any>

Comment: With your code also it should work. Plz provide the stackblitz link for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're code for the shared service looks like it should work. Are you sure that you have the same service instance in each component? In SharedService.ts change `@Injectable()` to `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` this will ensure the service is a singleton across the application.